# in python, is it possible for an exception to occur after a call but "before" the try block that follows it?

Tags: python, multithreading, exception, signals, keyboardinterrupt

Given a function call and a try block that immediately follows it, is there any scenario where the call returns normally but an exception is raised and not caught by the try block?

For example:

```py
# example 1
resource = acquire_a_resource()
try:
    resource.do_something()
    # some more code...
finally:
    resource.close()
```

Is it possible that `acquire_a_resource()` returns normally but `resource.close()` will not be called?

Or in other words, is there any scenario where:

```py
# example 2
resource = None
try:
    resource = acquire_a_resource()
    resource.do_something()
    # some more code...
finally:
    if resource:
        resource.close()
```

would be safer than example #1?

Maybe because of something to do with `KeyboardInterrupt`/threads/signals?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, at least in theory, though not in CPython (see footnote for details).  Threading is not particularly relevant, but your KeyboardInterrupt scenario is just right:

```
resource = acquire_a_resource()
```

calls the function.  The function acquires the resource and returns the handle, and then during the assignment to the variable,<sup>1</sup> the keyboard interrupt occurs.  So:

```
try:
```

does not run—the `KeyboardInterrupt` exception happens instead, leaving the current function and unbinding the variable.

The second version passes through the `finally` clause, so assuming `if resource` finds it boolean-truth-y, `resource.close()` does get called.

(Note that actually triggering this is often very difficult: you have to time the interrupt just right.  You can increase the race window a lot by, e.g., adding a `time.sleep(1)` before the `try`.)

For many cases, a `with` statement works well:

```
with acquire_a_resource() as resource:
    resource.do_something()
```

where the `close` is built into the `__exit__` method.  The method runs even if the block is escaped via exception.

---

<sup>1</sup>In general, the implementation is obligated to complete the binding of the acquired resource to the variable, otherwise there's an irrecoverable race.  In CPython this happens because the interpreter checks for interrupts between statements, and occasionally in strategic places in the source.

CPython actually adds another special case:

```c
    /* Do periodic things.  Doing this every time through
       the loop would add too much overhead, so we do it
       only every Nth instruction.  We also do it if
       ``pendingcalls_to_do'' is set, i.e. when an asynchronous
       event needs attention (e.g. a signal handler or
       async I/O handler); see Py_AddPendingCall() and
       Py_MakePendingCalls() above. */

    if (_Py_atomic_load_relaxed(&_PyRuntime.ceval.eval_breaker)) {
        opcode = _Py_OPCODE(*next_instr);
        if (opcode == SETUP_FINALLY ||
            opcode == SETUP_WITH ||
            opcode == BEFORE_ASYNC_WITH ||
            opcode == YIELD_FROM) {
            /* Few cases where we skip running signal handlers and other
               pending calls:
               - If we're about to enter the 'with:'. It will prevent
                 emitting a resource warning in the common idiom
                 'with open(path) as file:'.
               - If we're about to enter the 'async with:'.
               - If we're about to enter the 'try:' of a try/finally (not
                 *very* useful, but might help in some cases and it's
                 traditional)
               - If we're resuming a chain of nested 'yield from' or
                 'await' calls, then each frame is parked with YIELD_FROM
                 as its next opcode. If the user hit control-C we want to
                 wait until we've reached the innermost frame before
                 running the signal handler and raising KeyboardInterrupt
                 (see bpo-30039).
            */
            goto fast_next_opcode;
        }
```

(`Python/ceval.c`, near line 1000).

So actually the `try` line *does* run, in effect, because there's a `SETUP_FINALLY` here.  It's not at all clear to me whether other Python implementations do the same thing.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the `with` has the same interruption issue.

Comment: The `with` captures the resource *in the class object* (to which `resource` is bound later, when the `__enter__` returns).  The `__exit__` uses the class object's copy of the resource to do the close. This does mean that the resource manager itself must be coded carefully: construct the class with no resource bound, then acquire-and-bind in one operation. There's some degree of "chumminess" with the implementation: you have to assume that `var = acquire()` is itself atomic, i.e., that the "signal occurred, raise an exception" happens before or after the binding, not during (but that's so).

Comment: Even with a `with`, a KeyboardInterrupt can arrive between `acquire_a_resource()` succeeding and the `with` block getting set up (and that's ignoring the not-asked-about but even more dangerous possibility of a KeyboardInterrupt arriving *during* `acquire_a_resource`, or during `__exit__` or a `finally` block). KeyboardInterrupt is pretty nasty. I don't think there's really a safe way to deal with it without installing your own SIGINT handler.

Comment: If `acquire_a_resource` itself is non-atomic, you either have to hold off the ^C or write pretty heroic code, yes.

Comment: Incidentally, I've long thought that Python should have a function to defer keyboard interrupts (and signals in general), so that you could write: `with defer(...): code` where any signals in the `...` mask/set/list/whatever are held until the block exits.